# How to autoclose the bootstrap multiselect dropdown

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am unable to close the multi select dropdown after selected values in the dropdown. I have written the code below,

```
$("#EventCategoryDDL").multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    nonSelectedText: '-- Select Category --',
    autoClose: true
});
```

Comment: Multi-select dropdowns are generally a bad idea from the usability standpoint. Using checkboxes instead is a better idea.

Comment: here i am using checkboxes only

Comment: I think you posted a question about a multiselect dropdown, no?

Comment: yes , where  i used bootstrap multiselect plugin which inclueds checkboxes

Comment: I'm not following you, mate. You might wanna post a code snippet that's more complete than what you have now.

Comment: Actually i have multiselect dropdown after selecting the values in the dropdown  the dropdown is not getting closed then how should i close the dropdown after selecting the values from dropdown